# Base table or view not found: Many to many relation laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I have two models setup in many to many relation with pivot tabel `climbincludeds_tour`:

`Tour.php`

```
class Tour extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'tours';
  public function climbIncluded(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\ClimbIncluded',
                                'climbincludeds_tour',
                                'tour_id', 'cincluded_id');
    }
}
```

`ClimbIncluded.php`

```
class ClimbIncluded extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'climbincludeds';
    public function tours()
    {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tour');
    }
}
```

And I have a delete button on view attached to destroy method in `ClimbIncludedController.php`

```
    public function destroy(ClimbIncluded $climbIncluded)
{
    $climbIncluded->tours()->detach();
    $climbIncluded ->delete();
    Session::flash('success','Item sucessfully deleted !');
    return redirect()->route('climb.ie');
}
```

When I want to delete a record laravel returns an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'peak.tour_trek_included' 
doesn't exist (SQL: delete from `tour_trek_included` where `trek_included_id` = 1)
```

If I remove or comment out the `$climbIncluded->tours()->detach();` from the destroy method, laravel deletes the record without any error. I have passed name of pivot table as second argument to belongsToMany method also. What am I missing here ?

Comment: This seems like a weird interaction. Why don't you put a foreign key constraint with delete on the pivot table? This would allow you to delete the related models and not worry about cleaning up the relationship data.

Comment: Try `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: @Sandeesh sorry but I didn't get you. Can you explain in detail ?

Comment: @whoacowboy no luck with `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @TanjaForsberg `$table->integer('tour_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('tour_id')->references('id')->on('tours')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->integer('cincluded_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('cincluded_id')->references('id')->on('climbincludeds')->onDelete('cascade');` on your migration would add foreign key constraints. Which would would then auto delete the pivot table data when you delete a tour or climdincluded item

Comment: @Sandeesh Now I'm stuck on another error after adding code suggested by you. ` SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table` `peak`.`#sql-618_8d` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update") (SQL: alter table `climb_tou
  r` add constraint `climb_tour_tour_id_foreign` foreign key (`tour_id`) references `tours` (`id`) on delete cascade)`

Comment: @TanjaForsberg you've tried to add the foreign twice or the table already has it added. You should drop the table and add it correctly, or manually fix it.